# Unable to Detect Size of Brand new Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, mount, fdisk, df

I just purchased a 8TB hard drive today.

I just put it in my USB enclosure.

`fdisk -l` did see the device:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1404.5 GB, 1404493455360 bytes, 2743151280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

But the size isn't right that `fdisk` thinks it has only 1.4TB.

`df` also can't recognize the size correctly:

```
$ df /dev/sdc
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         8078104     0   8078104   0% /dev
```

Then, I ran `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` to try to delete all partitions (and there was none) and create a new one:

```
Command (m for help): d
No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-2743151279, default 2048): 
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-2743151279, default 2743151279): 
Using default value 2743151279
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 1.3 TiB is set
```

Any idea why 6.5TB is missing?  How can I get them back?

Thanks!

Update #1:
Followed James' suggestion, and `smartctl` did show 8TB.  So only the 2nd question remains -- how to get them back?

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     HGST HDN728080ALE604
Serial Number:    ........
LU WWN Device Id: ........
Firmware Version: A4GNW91X
User Capacity:    8,001,563,222,016 bytes [8.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Feb 15 20:29:41 2019
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  101) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (1184) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
 22 Unknown_Attribute       0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   222   222   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 23/33)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Update #2:
Now, I directly connects to the HDD instead of through USB + enclosure. 
  `fdisk` shows the correct total size of 8TB:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 8001.6 GB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

However, `df` still shows only 1.22TB:

```
$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc            1349915988    77848 1281242976   1% /run/media/myuser/xyz
```

Here is what `/proc/partitions` has:

```
$ sudo grep sdc /proc/partitions 
   8       32 7814026584 sdc
```

Any idea?

Comment: That isn't output from `df`.

Comment: `df` is useless to diagnose this. It shows free space of mounteda  file systems, not the total physical space of a device.

Comment: Also, what happens if you connect it to a SATA port instead of some USB stuff?

Comment: @Sven I will try to connect directly later if there is no solution.  Always good to know what's going on.  Thanks for your suggestion tho!

Comment: What does `grep sdc /proc/partitions` say?

Comment: @sven better but `df` still doesn't see the full size.

Comment: @rfc2460 updated with the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your USB enclose only supports 32-bit LBA. This is not enough for drives larger than 2 TiB.

According to `smartctl`, your drive is 8,001,563,222,016 bytes, which means 15,628,053,168 512-byte sectors. Your USB enclose, however, reports 2,743,151,280 sectors. If we take a look at the binary representation, the issue is obvious:

```
15,628,053,168 = 11 1010 0011 1000 0001 0010 1010 1011 0000
 2,743,151,280 =    1010 0011 1000 0001 0010 1010 1011 0000
```

Get a new, modern, USB enclose. A firmware update may be able to help, but there’s probably none available.

Comment: Good catch!  Now I tried to connect directly.  # of sectors looks correct now but `df` still doesn't show the full free space.  Idea?

Comment: You most likely created the partition while the disk was in the USB enclosure, right? You have to recreate or resize the partition then.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run `smartctl` to show the device information:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdc
```

(If smartctl isn't installed, then you need to do `yum install smartmontools`)

This should show you output containing an "INFORMATION SECTION" at the top, which should contain (amongst other things) the manufacturer, model and serial number - for example:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD60EFRX-68L0BN1
Serial Number:    ...elided...
LU WWN Device Id: ...elided...
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    6,001,175,126,016 bytes [6.00 TB]
```

If this doesn't show what you're expecting, then it's either *not* an 8TB drive, or you're looking at the wrong drive perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It does show 8TB in the "INFORMATION SECTION".  So continue on my second question in my post -- how can I get them back?  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried using devices this size in the same USB enclosure before? Could be that something strange is going on inside there.

Comment: First time using something bigger than 1.5TB with this enclosure.  Let me take sven's suggestion to try to connect directly and see what my system sees then.  Thanks!